# $\gcd(ac,b) \geq \gcd(b,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How could one prove that $ \gcd(ac,b) \geq \gcd(c,b) $?

**My try:-**  If we multiply $c$ by $a$, gcd(a,b) would multiply the gcd(c,b) to give gcd(ac,b).

But can we think of this in more vigorous mathematical terms?

I mean how would it be if we go like the smallest positive number in the set $S = \{cx+by\mid x,y\in \Bbb Z\}$ is never greater than the smallest positive number in the set $P = \{acx+by\mid x,y\in \Bbb Z\}$

Comment: If $d=\gcd (b,c)$ then $d\,|\,ac$ and $d\,|\, b$ so $d\,|\,\gcd(ac,b)$.

Comment: @lulu Fine! But It might be interesting to go through the definition of gcd itself

Comment: What do you mean?  This uses the definition of the gcd.

Comment: @lulu I mean how would it be if we go like the smallest positive number in the set S = {cx+by|x,y$\epsilon $ N} is never greater than the smallest positive number in the set P = {acx+by|x,y$\epsilon $ N}

Comment: That isn't the definition of the gcd.  The gcd is the greatest common divisor.  That's all you need here.  Well, technically, I use the fact that every common divisor divides the gcd which is true but not obvious.  But you don't need to use that.  The fact that $d$ is a common divisor of $ac$ and $b$ already proves that it is $≤gcd(ac,b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could go the way you suggested : if you were to say that $\gcd(c,b) = \min\{cx+by : x,y \in \mathbb Z\}$ then call the set $\{cx+by : x,y \in \mathbb Z\} \cap \mathbb N$ as $P$ and $\{acx + by : x,y \in \mathbb Z\} \cap \mathbb N$ as $Q$. We would have $\gcd(c,b) = \min P$ and $\gcd(ac,b) = \min Q$.

If we show that $Q \subset P$, we are done? For then the smallest element of $Q$ (which exists as $Q$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$) is also in $P$ so is bigger than the smallest element of $P$.

So show that $Q \subset P$. Your hint : If $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $a \in \mathbb Z$ then $ax \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

If a number $n$ divides both $c$ and $b$, then $n$ must divide both $ac$ and $b$ too. If follows that $n \le \mathrm{gcd}(ac,b)$.

Let $n = \mathrm{gcd}(c,b)$.